# Javascript Augmented Modules: Why assign IIFE to module when passing module in as argument?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm new to the augmented module pattern and I've seen this example a lot:

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {

    my.method = function () {
        // added method...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE));
```

I was wondering why I need to assign this IIFE to MODULE in the first place, when I'm passing in MODULE as an argument to the IIFE.

For example, this gives the same result:

```
(function (my) {

    my.method = function () {
        // added method...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE));
```

(provided MODULE has already been declared).

So my question is: is either fine? If so, why do all the examples I see use the first one? It seems to me like MODULE is assigned 'method' twice.
Is it just the case that MODULE is declared like this in the first example, in case it doesn't already exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing that literal example a lot, you're probably seeing poor examples.

You're quite correct that there's no need to assign the result back to the variable if you're not going to return a different object.

But normally, the example is this:

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {

    my.method = function () {
        // added method...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
//      ^^^^^^---------- note
```

...which makes assigning it back to the `MODULE` variable essential, in case nothing has created the object yet. If nothing has created the object yet, `MODULE` will be `undefined` and so `MODULE || {}` will evaluate to the newly-created object.

> It seems to me like MODULE is assigned 'method' twice.

Not unless the code runs twice.

> Is it just the case that MODULE is declared like this in the first example, in case it doesn't already exist?

Yes. It's so that if you have several different files that define different parts of `MODULE`, the order they run in doesn't matter (provided they don't try to *use* parts that haven't been defined yet).

---

There are a lot of variations on this theme. For instance:

Variation 1:

```
var MODULE = MODULE || {};
(function(my) {
    // ...
})(MODULE);
```

Variation 2:

```
var MODULE;
(function(my) {
    // ...
})(MODULE = MODULE || {});
```

The advantage to writing either of those variations over the example at the top of the answer is that you don't have to remember to return `my` at the end of the function. (Of course, if you forget, it'll blow up fairly early and you'll find and fix the bug quite quickly, so it's a *really small* advantage.)